# Where should additional files be put when writing my own magento extension?

Tags: structure, recommendation-engine, magento

I'm writing my magento extension and came up with a question. The main extension files/directory structure is quite clear. We have dirs for extension configuration files, models, helpers, database resources, frontend and backend scripts and stylesheets etc.

But what if my extension uses some files that aren't classes or resources to be included to frontend or backend?

For instance: image files that will only be attached to emails and will never be retrieved by a browser directly.

**Should/could I just create a directory /app/code/community/MyNamespace/MyExtensionName/images?**

The same dir tree for better readability:

```
app
    code
        community
            MyNamespace
                MyExtensionName
                    images
```

**Or is there any other correct/recommended way to achieve that?**

Comment: Good question MagGNetas...

Comment: why you want to add image files through module ??..there are very other ways of adding images..

Comment: It's not only images. It's the resources my module's gonna use, but not for displaying. They will not be uploaded later on. It's just some resources that will come embedded into the module so they could be used by my models and/or helpers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's never been clear guidance on how to do this from Magento Inc. itself, and Magento's module structure doesn't offer clear guidance.  The approach I've always taken is

1. Pretend I'm on the Magento core team
2. Pretend my fellow team members are sociopaths who don't care if anything I've done breaks

If you're adding frontend files for public consumption (to `js`, `skin`, `etc`), I always create a folder that's a lowercase version of my full module name, and drop all files in there

```
/js/namespace_modulename/file.js
```

In the case of files that aren't going to be served publicly (i.e. you only need access to them via PHP), creating a folder in the root of your module (as you've done above) is appropriate.  I'd suggest something like

```
app
    code
        community
            MyNamespace
                MyExtensionName
                    assets
                        images
```

You never know when there'll be something else you want to add, and having everything under one folder will help keep the module structure clean.

There's even sort of a precedent for this in Magento's core code.  Take a look at the

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/doc
```

folder.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that Sales/doc case either after going through all Mage modules looking for an answer :) And of course combining my pseudo resources into single directory goes without saying. I only gave images example as a reference. I'm sure this will work (in fact it does). I'm just wondering if that's the "correct" way of doing this. Sticking with this method for now. Thank you, Alan.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder into media directory and place your files/images into that folder

```
media
     MyExtensionName
                images
```

And access them like

```
 echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'/MyExtensionName/images/pic.jpg';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ahmed. I know it's one way to do it but is this actually the best practice/correct way? Images aren't the only resources I'm using and I'm never accessing them directly for displaying.

Comment: Correct way ? yes.
Best practice ? as Alan said "There's never been clear guidance on how to do this from Magento"

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm sticking to the original idea so far unless something new comes up. Take care